# How to get/view crash reports of iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello friends my app is crashing multiple times. In iTunes-store app-analytics it shows no.of crashes but how can I view or get crash report of that particular app.

I'm using Xcode 7.3 for development.

I have seen various answer's about this but not able understand properly.

I just need to check, why my app is getting crash, for that purpose I need to see crash report. Or if there is any other way to see it?

Can we check in source-code, actually at what line app is getting cash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open Xcode

Go to Window -> Organizer

1. You will be presented a window with two options on title bar "Archives" and "Crashes".
2. On left pan select your app from the list given.
3. And choose "Crashes"
4. You can view crash reports of all the version submitted to App Store.
5. Click on "Open in Project" from right hand side panel to go to exact line of the issue in your project.

**Note:**
Crash reports are retrieved only when the user accepts to send diagnostics back to Apple.

**Edit**
For best third party crash report tools
https://savvyapps.com/blog/review-5-best-ios-crash-reporting-tools-infographic

Comment: You are welcome. Accept it as answer if you find it suits your need, will be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics) from twitter. It will give you detailed crash report.

Answer (score 1):

For native you can check the crashes in Xcode -> Window -> Organizer.

You can use Crashlytics. Check details here for [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install). Further, you can use Fabric application in the mobile to get notifications of crashes and will also send mail for the same.